# When trying to add the opus package into PyCharm I get the following error

Tags: python, discord, package, bots, opus

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opus (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for opus
```

I did `brew install opus` and it shows up in brew list.

Any ideas?

I need it to operate a bot on discord, which is supposed to join a specific channel and play a sound at a specific time.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that the modules you install on command prompt(windows)/terminal(mac) don't get uploaded on pycharm projects.

Try doing this:

> Open the project
> Click File -> Settings -> Project: (project name) -> Python Interpreter -> Click on the '+' sign ->
> type in the name of the package you need in the search bar -> Click 'Install'

If that doesn't work, it means that your project's interpreter does not support the package you want.